# Whats a word for saying that someone said something but later turned around on it?

Tags: grammar, phrasing

*Im trying to find a proper word or phrase to describe this situation.*

> A person initially claimed that theres no pollution. Then later he or
>   she turned around to say that there is some pollution due to faulty
>   system. The latter statement detracts from the initial claims.

Wanted to know if theres a term, word or phrase that can be used to describe this.

Currently Im just using "turned around on his or her initial statement" but it sounds odd and wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this word to cover the situation where the speaker recants the original claim, or the one where he talks as if he had never said original, or both?

Comment: Are they coming clean and admitting they lied before? Or are they  saying they never said the first thing?  Or are they saying that they were wrong initially and are correcting themselves?

Comment: Hi, to Mary's question its more like speaker says something that goes against the original claim. To Jim's question, the person who made the initial claim did not allude to retract the original, so its contradictory. In a way admitting the first claim was wrong but yet not showing signs that they are correcting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options based on the situation:

If the person says the opposite of an earlier statement you could say they "contradict" themselves. This could be purposeful or unintentional or deceitful.

If the person purposefully changes an earlier position you could say they the "recant" or "retract" their earlier statement.